# Функция принимает числовую последовательность - 5 целых чисел. swift

Tags: swift

Не могу понять что не так?
Вот задача:
Функция принимает числовую последовательность - 5 целых чисел. Проверить, упорядочена ли последовательность по неубыванию. Если упорядочена вывести на экран yes, в противном случае вывести no. Задача решается без использования циклов.

Input example:
1 2 3 4 5

Output example:
yes

Naming rule:
func isSorted(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int)

Решение:

```
    func isSorted(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int) {
    if a < b && b < c && c < d && d < e {
        print("yes")
    } else {
      print("no")  
    } 
}

isSorted(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`по неубыванию` означает, что сравнение нестрогое

```
if a <= b и т.д.
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Думаю, это отвечает на вопрос `что не так?`